# Google Sheets: Conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to do conditional formatting on a sheet, by comparing cell values between them on a same line.

For example (based on the shared screenshot below), I would like to highlight on line 3 the cell B3 (because it's the higher avg price / box compared to F3, J3 and N3). Etc...

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks for you help! :)

Sample screenshot:
[image: Sample screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the below formula in the conditional formatting window with the range selected as `B3:B, F3:F, J3:J, N3:N`

```
=B3=MAX($B3,$F3,$J3,$N3)
```

Sample Screenshot:
[image: Sample Screenshot of Conditional Formatting]

Note: formula in the screenshot is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @Gangula but this doesn't look to work. There is an issue on the formula.
I'm sharing a copy of the file in case you want to test it live: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1981K0k3j5N8D1IvNWnckBwRpf4tZDQihR2BF36KgQ4k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see that you edited your answer but still it doesn't work out.
Here is the screenshot: https://ibb.co/1JxK9GL

Comment: based on your regional language settings, you might have to use semi-colon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`) in a formula. So try this: `=B3=MAX($B3;$G3;$L3;$Q3)`